# Firestore Spinner error passing list after retrieving data

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-spinner

I'm trying to populate a spinner but for some reason I'm getting an error when trying to pass through my list of objects. Can some take a look please:

code:

```
public class AddFacultyFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.spinner_search_UniFac)
Spinner spinner_search_UniFac;
ArrayList<University> list = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_faculty,
            container,
            false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference docRef = db.collection("university");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>) task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for(DocumentSnapshot a : task.getResult()){
                University u = new University();
                u.setID(a.getId());
                u.setDesc(a.get("Desc").toString());
                list.add(u);
            }
        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<University> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<University>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    list);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
            .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_search_UniFac.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    return view;
}

public AddFacultyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

}
```

Thank you in advance. This is the error

> error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(AddFacultyFragment,int,List)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; AddFacultyFragment cannot be converted to Context)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; AddFacultyFragment cannot be converted to Context)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; AddFacultyFragment cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: Using the right context does your list get populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you missing is the correct context. You cannot use `this` on a fragment, you have to use `getContext()` then it should work. Like this:

public class AddFacultyFragment extends Fragment {

```
@BindView(R.id.spinner_search_UniFac)
Spinner spinner_search_UniFac;
ArrayList<University> list = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_faculty,
            container,
            false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference docRef = db.collection("university");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>) task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for(DocumentSnapshot a : task.getResult()){
                University u = new University();
                u.setID(a.getId());
                u.setDesc(a.get("Desc").toString());
                list.add(u);
            }
        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<University> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<University>
            (getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    list);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
            .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_search_UniFac.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    return view;
}

public AddFacultyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

}
```